# Chef Solo easy_install an egg file?

Tags: chef-infra

Has anyone been able to get Chef Solo to install a python .egg file that I have provided somewhere?

```
easy_install_package "myeggfile"
   action: install
   ???
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`easy_install_package` documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_easy_install_package.html), you should use the `source` attribute for using a local file:

```
easy_install_package 'name' do
  source '/path/on/disk/to/my.egg'
end
```